# Livestamp Plugin Jquery - how to show a time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I use this jquery plugin: [livestamp](http://mattbradley.github.io/livestampjs/).
If you know, tell please, how to show time (**hours**, **minutes** ago) **only** for the current day. After 24 hours on next day - to show label **"yesterday"** or simple **date**.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

By default, I don't think livestamp can do this.

But, at the bottom of livestamp's examples, they have some code to animate the text when it changes by hooking into the `change.livestamp` event.

We can use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to modify this code to do what you're asking.

```
$('#animation').on('change.livestamp', function(event, from, to) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Stop the text from changing automatically

    // Get the original timestamp out of the event
    var originalTS = event.timeStamp;
    // Make a new moment object to compare the timestamp to
    var newDate = moment();
    // Use moment's .diff method to get the ms difference between timestamps
    var delta = newDate.diff(originalTS);

    // If the difference is less than a day's worth of ms
    if (delta < 86400000){
        // Use formatted text provided by the change event
        $(this).html(to);
    }
    else {
        // Format the moment object with whatever moment format you want
        $(this).html( newDate.format("dddd M/D/YYYY") );
    }
}).livestamp();
```

I haven't used livestamp, but it seems to rely on moment existing for its formatting options, so this should just work.

Livestamp's source is [super small](https://github.com/mattbradley/livestampjs/blob/master/livestamp.js), so consider hacking on it yourself if you have other stuff you want to be able to do.